# How to modify an integer using Bash sed

Tags: bash, sed

I have an XML node like this:

```
<point type="2D" x="61" y="273" />
```

I wish to multiply `x` by 2 using Bash. I had tried the following:

```
echo '<rect key="frame" x="61" y="273" width="199" height="21"/>' | sed "s/x=\"\([[:digit:]]*\)\"/x=\"$((\1 * 2))\"/"
```

But it failed with:

```
syntax error: operand expected (error token is "\\1 * 2")
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy to achieve with perl:

```
perl -p -e 's/x="([0-9]+)"/"x=\"".($1*2)."\""/e' input.xml
```

To replace directly, add -i like you would with sed.

Comment: as I said: if you add the -i flag all occurences of x="somenumber" will be affected.
Or did you mean x, y, someothervalue?
This can be done the same way.

Answer (score 3):

`sed` is not the the right tool for this. You can use this gnu awk command with a custom **record separator**:

```
awk -v RS='.*x="|".*' '!NF{ s=RT } NF{ print s $1*2 RT }' file
<point type="2D" x="122" y="273" />
```

However it is better to use a proper XML parser for thorough XML parsing.